# magento product export only includes base, small, and thumbnail images

Tags: product-images, migration, export

I'm in the process of migrating our magento 2 store elsewhere, and in doing a product export I noticed that it only includes the base, small, and thumnail images (which are typically all the same image for us). Our products generally have at least 4 images, to show all sides of a product. Is there a way to export all of our product images?

Note that I only have access to admin, as we're having an issue with obstructionist developers who would prefer we didn't migrate.

Answer (score 0):

To export products from Magento 2 with selected fields, you can either use a third-party module or create a standalone script. I have done this for a customer before because Magento 2's built-in export feature has limited functionality, which may not meet out expectations.